# connect android app to sqlite through odbc

Tags: sqlite, odbc, android-studio-2.2

I am trying to create a simple app to Learn how to connect Android App to SQLite using ODBC.

I know I can directly use SQLite database in Android app but my SQLite database is on my desktop and I want to connect it through App(mobile and desktop are on same WiFi).

I want to use this database in other Java app too.

Please Guide.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: SQLite is not a client/server database.

Comment: You might be interested in [SQLitening](http://www.planetsquires.com/sqlite_client_server.htm)

Comment: See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/21/114927

Comment: Thank you for all your replies....I a trying now to connect my app through SQLitening... Thanks again.